# String concatenation without altering original values - C

Tags: c, string-concatenation, strcat

I am making a dynamic PUT request through the use of string concatenation with C. My problem is that after the first request, a string that I need to remain static `putEndpoint`, is altered with the string concatenation I'm using it for.

```
char putEndpoint[] = "PUT /api/v1/products/";
char http[] = " HTTP/1.1";
char productID[idLen];

for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
  productID[i] = newTag[i];
}

// going into this strcat, putEndpoint correctly = "PUT /api/v1/products/"

char *putRequestID = strcat(putEndpoint,productID);

// putEndpoint now = "PUT /api/v1/products/xxxxxxxxxxx"

char *putRequestEndpoint = strcat(putRequestID,http);
```

Now if I were to make a 2nd call (which I will need to do), `putEndpoint` initializes as `"PUT /api/v1/products/xxxxxxxxxxx"`.

> EDIT: Is there an alternative to `strcat()` that could accomplish this concatenation? 
>   I now understand that `strcat()` is meant to alter values.

Comment: You have some nasty bugs in there...

Comment: @PaulR care to elaborate?

Comment: Why not make a temporary variable that just stores `putEndpoint`s value and then just set `putEndpoint` equal to this temp variable?

Comment: Read about `strcat` it concatenates second string into first one . Result - String 1 is modified.

Comment: `strcat` does not allocate new string. It simply appends data to 1st arg. That is it changes `putEndpoint` several times.

Comment: @user4419802 I hadn't realized that - is there an alternative that would allocate a new string?

Comment: @LaurenF Several. For example, `strdup`+ `strcat`.

Comment: Since all 3 strings that are to be concatenated have maximum sizes, form a destination array that is about the sum of those sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing `putEndpoint` to a constant and created a buffer array and that I then copied `putEndpoint` into. This array then resets after each request.

```
const char putEndpoint[] = "PUT /api/v1/products/";
char http[] = " HTTP/1.1";
char productID[idLen];

char putRequestBuffer[100];
strcpy(putRequestBuffer, putEndpoint);
strcat(putRequestBuffer, productID);

char *putRequestEndpoint = strcat(putRequestBuffer,http);
```

Comment: How does code know `char putRequestBuffer[100]` is sufficiently large?  Better to use _something_ like  `char putRequestBuffer[sizeof putEndpoint + sizeof http + sizeof productID];`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`sprintf`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm).

[A simple working example](https://ideone.com/18xPkV)-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 int main(void) {

      char putEndpoint[] = "PUT /api/v1/products/";
      char http[] = " HTTP/1.1";
      char *putRequestEndpoint;

      putRequestEndpoint=malloc(strlen(putEndpoint)+strlen(http)+1); //allocating memory

      sprintf(putRequestEndpoint,"%s%s",putEndpoint,http); // formatted output is stored in putRequestEndpoint
      printf("%s\n",putRequestEndpoint);
      printf("%s",putEndpoint); // will print original string unchanged.
      free(putRequestEndpoint);  //freeing memory
      return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`memcpy` and static arrays with a fixed size and proper bounds checking are your friend, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to reset it with code. If you change `putEndpoint[]` to a const, which will make your first line look like

```
const char putEndpoint[] = "PUT /api/v1/products/";
```

the compiler will give you an error the first time you `strcat(putEndpoint,...)` because strcat will be trying to write to the constant variable. This will force you to find an alternative solution.

The code below cleanly allocates temporary memory for the endpoint string as needed, copies the first string into it, concatenates the next two onto it, uses it, and finally de-allocates it and sets the pointer back to NULL.

```
int lengthEndpoint = 0;
char* putRequestEndpoint = NULL;

lengthEndpoint = strlen(putEndpoint) + strlen(productID) + strlen(http);
lengthEndpoint += 1; // add room for null terminator

putRequestEndpoint = malloc(lengthEndpoint);
strcpy(putRequestEndpoint, putEndpoint);
strcat(putRequestEndpoint, productID);
strcat(putRequestEndpoint, http);

// do something with putRequestEndpoint

free(putRequestEndpoint);
putRequestEndpoint = NULL;
```

Before answering this, I refreshed my memory of C string manipulation using this [WIKIBOOKS site](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Strings). I'd recommend it for further reading on this subject.